# Compose ngrx selector combining MemoizedSelector with plain selector

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-selectors

I have a large project that's slowly migrating to the new `ngrx` syntax. We have many selectors that are plain functions like this:

```
export function appDetailsSelector(state$: Observable<AppState>): Observable<AppDetails> {
    return state$.pipe(map((appState: AppState) => appState.appDetails));
}
```

New selectors are written using `createSelector`:

```
export const selectUserConfig: MemoizedSelector<AppState, UserConfig> = createSelector(
  selectUserData,
  (userData: UserData) => userData.config,
);
```

Both of these use the same state shape, but how do I combine to create a new selector combining both of these with `createSelector`?

I know I can use piping to do this in the component code:

```
combineLatest([
  this.store.pipe(appDetailsSelector),
  this.store.select(selectUserConfig),
], (appDetails, userConfig) => ...projector fn code...);
```

But this isn't reusable and I need it done with `createSelector` to avoid repeating this in multiple components. If `appDetailsSelector` was created with `createSelector` it would look like this:

```
export const getUserBookmarks = createSelector(
  appDetailsSelector,
  selectUserConfig,
  (appDetails: AppDetails, userConfig: UserConfig) => appDetails.useBookmarks ? userConfig.bookmarks : []
);
```

But this `Argument of type 'MemoizedSelector<AppState, UserConfig, DefaultProjectorFn<UserConfig>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SelectorWithProps<Observable<AppState>, unknown, UserConfig>'.   Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.     Type 'Observable<AppState>' is missing the following properties from type 'AppState'...`

I can see that the old style selectors take `Observable<AppState>` and the new ones assume `AppState`; how to bridge this gap and combine these two selectors?

Answer (score 1):

You can use typecasting

```typescript
export const getUserBookmarks = createSelector(
  appDetailsSelector as MemoizedSelector<AppState, UserConfig, DefaultProjectorFn<UserConfig>>,
  selectUserConfig as MemoizedSelector<AppState, UserConfig, DefaultProjectorFn<UserConfig>>,
  (appDetails: AppDetails, userConfig: UserConfig) => appDetails.useBookmarks ? userConfig.bookmarks : []
);
```

Typecasting will set the type to the same type

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to use `Observable` selectors with the new `createSelector` syntax. Observable selectors operate on an observable, while function selectors operate on the data contained within the observable directly; there's no out-of-the-box way to make these work together.

Note that an observable selector is actually a function selector in disguise; if you need to maintain your classic selectors, just move the stateful logic out into a function selector and use the correct selector per-context.

```js
export const appDetailsSelector = (state: AppState) => state.appDetails;

export const appDetailsObservableSelector = (state$: Observable<AppState>) =>
  state$.pipe(map(appDetailsSelector));
```